# Type of responses includes in JMeter Throughput

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing, throughput

I want to know if in the summary report in JMeter, the Throughput value correspond to all responses code (200, 201, 404, 500) or if correspond only for the success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [JMeter Glossary](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)

> Throughput is calculated as requests/unit of time. The time is calculated from the start of the first sample to the end of the last sample. This includes any intervals between samples, as it is supposed to represent the load on the server.
>
> The formula is: Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time).

So all the requests independent of status code are considered.

See [The Load Reports](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65153-the-load-reports) for more metrics explained including the throughput one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the value in bytes given on the summary results will display throughput for all response types.  However, it will aggregate that with all response codes for the specific label of that sampler.  For example: If you have a request named "Log In" which has 1 success and 9 failures during run time.  This will cause all ten sample throughputs to be averaged.

Also, remember that most of the error response codes such as 304 (not modified), 404 (not found), 500 (internal server error) or 401 (unauthorized) will typically have much smaller response bodies than your 200s *(assuming big html payloads, not smaller services)*.  That could explain why you might be seeing much lower throughput numbers for those response values.

If you need to calculate the throughput of only a specific response code on a specific sampler, you will have to edit the JTL file after run time and remove the irrelevant data.  Then use CMDRunner.jar from the plugin packages to re-compile your summary statistics.  To continue the example above, you would remove the single success of "Log In" and recompile summary statistics with only the 9 failed samples you wish to calculate throughput on.